# How do I check if the function is integrable (Lebesgue) on R?

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral

Is $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}((-1)^{n}/n) $ Lebesgue integrable on R?

Comment: Should the summation be from $n = 1$?  Or the denominator in the leading fraction be $n+1$?  Otherwise the value on $[0, 1)$ is a problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to worry about the alternating series: One of the basic theorems of the Lebesgue integral is that a measurable function $f$ is integrable if and only if $g(x)=\lvert f(x)\rvert$ is (with finite integral).

In your case, there holds $$g=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\chi_{[n,n+1)}\text.$$

Now put $$g_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n\chi_{[n,n+1)}\text.$$ By the definition of the integral, there holds $$\int_{\mathbf R}g_N(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n\text.$$

Since $g_N(x)$ converges monotonically increasing to $g(x)$ as $N\to\infty$ (for every $x\in\mathbf R$), the monotone convergence theorem implies
$$\int_{\mathbf R}g_N(x)\,dx\to\int_{\mathbf R}g(x)\,dx\qquad(N\to\infty)\text.$$
Hence,
$$\int_{\mathbf R}g(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=\infty\text,$$
and so $g$ is not Lebesgue integrable (with a finite integral). It follows that also $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: I think I get it! Thanks for the help!